# Putting two columns one below other, with sidebar

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I'm stuck on this layout issue, where I want to put two columns one below the other, on the right side, and I want to keep navigation on the left side. I'm currently having this layout:

[image]

The problem is, they are not placed right. I want them to be aligned exactly one below the other, something like this: 
[image]

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        @include('partials.admin-sidebar')
        <div class="col-md-10">
            // first column layout
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            // Second column layout
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

The navigation sidebar that I'm including:

```
<div class="col-lg-2">
        //Sidebar layout
</div>
```

Is there any easy fix that could solve this problem. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding bootstrap 4 utilities `justify-content-end`to your `row` which you wanna align right. It would be helpful if you make a working snippet

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        @include('partials.admin-sidebar')
        <div class="col-md-10">
            // first column layout
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            // Second column layout
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Solution2:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-10">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
      <div class="col-lg-12"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First solution was exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Glad that i could help you. Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using bootstrap. Try this:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        @include('partials.admin-sidebar')
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            // first column layout
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2">
            // Empty column
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            // Second column layout
        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `HTML` is Wrong, Change Your `HTML` Like.

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    @include('partials.admin-sidebar')
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                // first column layout
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                // Second column layout
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@stop
```